Auto inherite a parent class with decorator
I have a class decorator p() that can be used only on classes that inherite from some abstract class P.
So anytime someone uses p it should be written as follows:
@p()
class Child(P):
    ...

Is there any way to automatically inherite P using the decorator p() so it would simply be written as follows:
@p()
class Child:
    ...


It might be easier to go the other way around, and bake the decorator's function into the parent class (so you'd write class Child(SpecialP) and you'd get the effect of the p decorator too. Do you need to pass arguments to the decorator that might differ from child to child?

@Blckknght No it won't work, my decorator does changes to the init function of the child class. It wont work doing it to the parent class.

My idea would be to add the effects of the decorator to the parent class's __init_subclass__ method. It's harder to change an existing class's parent class after it's been defined (as it will have been by the time a decorator can get to it).

Or, define an intermediate class that inherts from P and from which Child inherits, and have its __init__ method do whatever p is doing to Child's __init__ method.

@chepner wouldn't work in my case  unless the intermediate class has the same attributes as the Child class. But the init_subclass works

As I commented, it's tricky to apply a base class using a decorator the way you asked. However, it is a lot easier if you try an alternative approach, where the decorator's behavior is incorporated into the base class, rather than the other way around.
Here's an example, that prints out a message before calling the child class's __init__ method:
from functools import wraps

class Base:
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        original_init = cls.__init__

        @wraps(cls.__init__)
        def wrapper(self, *args):
            print("foo")
            original_init(self, *args)

        cls.__init__ = wrapper


class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print("bar")

You can customize the wrapper function's behavior to do whatever your decorator currently does (rather than just printing a message). And of course, the base class can have whatever other behavior you want the derived class to inherit, rather than just the __init_subclass__ machinery that enables changing the subclass's __init__ method.
